# What can I do about this MariaDB 10.0 error?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

I have a serious error that crashes the mariadb service, and it won't start up again until I delete the database folder in the data directory of the database I was working on at the time. Here is the .err file printout. Anyone know what to do about this?

```
2015-02-21 13:48:23 7dc InnoDB: FTS Optimize Removing table bolingerfield/tag
2015-02-21 13:49:44 4bc4  InnoDB: Error: space id and page n:o stored in the page
InnoDB: read in are 13924:3, should be 13877:3!
2015-02-21 13:49:44 4bc4  InnoDB: Error: space id and page n:o stored in the page
InnoDB: read in are 13924:1, should be 13877:1!
2015-02-21 13:50:23 798  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 1944 in file btr0btr.cc line 713
InnoDB: Failing assertion: mach_read_from_4(seg_header + FSEG_HDR_SPACE) == space
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
```

Comment: I'd do what it's telling you to do in the above output...

Answer (score 3):

You may have moved around manually the tablespaces or improperly importing the tables physically. The error assertion is a detection by MySQL InnoDB that pages have internal values that do not correspond to their physical location, thus forcing the kill of the server to avoid further corruption.

I have very very rarely seen that as a problem due to InnoDB programming (at least on upstream and stable MySQL), and more usually due to a problem in datafile or configuration management by an operator. While it should be possible to go back to a consistent state, without knowing more about what kind of processes you have performed, I would start by recommending performing a bull backup of your system so no data is lost.

Comment: It was quite a pickle. I was generating the database from scratch with an orm and inserting data randomly into it so I could test it. I wrote almost none of the sql myself. Maybe Nhibernate or MySQL.data.dll is generating dangerous queries. But I'm unable to replicate this crash because it happens maybe 1/20 times. Baffling.

Comment: Happy to know that databases have something of a sprinkler system to put the fire out before it causes major damage, though. Pretty neat.

Comment: @IBC queries done using the mysql API should not create such state. Almost all databases have such safe measures. InnoDB in particular has a checksum of every 16K block (aka "page") to ensure consistency at all times. Maybe your configuration or hardware has some problem, or it has not been properly updated.